# are singletons always closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am learning about metric spaces and I find it very confusing. Is this a valid proof that a singleton must be closed?

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, to show that $\{a\}$ is closed, let's show that $X \setminus \{a\}$ is open. Choose $y \in X \setminus \{a\}$ and set $\epsilon = d(a,y)$. Then since $a \not \in B(y,\epsilon)$, we have that $B(y,\epsilon) \subset X \setminus \{a\}$ so that $X \setminus \{a\}$ is open.

Comment: Your proof is ok.

Comment: Yes, this is fine. For intuition think of the real line. If we remove a single point, say $0$, then the remaining portion $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0,\infty)$ is open since we can get arbitrarily close to $0$ without ever leaving this set.

Comment: Singletons sets are always closed in a Hausdorff space and it is easy to show that metric spaces are Hausdorff.  Afterall, for a general topological space one could just nilly willy define some singleton sets as open.

Comment: I would add to the proof that $B$ were the *open* ball. The notation is not very standard, may mean the closed ball too (that contains $a$).

Comment: Related question: I'm reading up the article on compact space in Wikipedia, which says that a subset of Euclidean space is closed if it contains all its limit points. But since a singleton set doesn't have any limit points, is it correct to say that the set is closed because the statement above is vacuously true?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your proof is okay. More generally, we can define any [topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space) to be [$T_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space) if its singleton sets are closed (or equivalently, for any points $x \neq y$, there is an open set containing $x$ and not containing $y$). $T_1$ is an example of a [separation axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom). You've shown that metric spaces are $T_1$, but much stronger separation axioms hold for metric spaces.

Credit to Squirtle for providing similar details in a comment.