# Consider a two-point set $M = \{a,b\}$ whose topology consists of the two sets, $M$ and the empty set.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Consider a two-point set $M = \{a,b\}$ whose topology consists of the two sets, $M$ and the empty set. Why does this topology not arise from a metric on M?

May someone please clarify this question (I'm new to analysis)!
Does it have anything to do with the fact that $\{a\}, \{b\}$ are each closed sets and their complements, $\{b\}$ and $\{a\},$ respectively, are also closed sets?

Comment: $\{a\},\{b\}$ are NOT closed.

Comment: I thought all singletons were closed?

Comment: Can you clear up that confusion?

Comment: Singletons are closed when the topology arises from a metric, but we are questioning that.  The definition of a closed set is the complement of an open set.  In a two point set if a singleton is not open, as here, its complement, which is the other singleton, is not closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are not closed because their complements are not open.  The only closed sets are $\emptyset$ and $M$.  If there is a metric on the space, the only thing of interest is $d(a,b)=k$.  Then the open ball around $a$ of radius $\frac k2$ only includes $a$, so $\{a\}$ must be open but it is not.  Therefore the topology does not arise from a metric.

Comment: Why must it be open given radius $r = \frac{k}{2}?$ Is it become given $r$, all of the elements within $r$ of $a$ (namely, $a$) are contained within the set $M.$? You could have also picked $r$ to be $r>k?$

Comment: And, why is $\{a\}$ not open? Given that there exists some $r>0$ such that all elements within $r$ of $a$ are contained within the set (doesn't any $r$ work – if $r\leq k$, the ball around $a$ contains only $a,$ and $a$ is an element in $M;$ if $r>k,$ the ball contains only $a$ and $b,$ both of which are elements in $M.$

Comment: When you derive a topology from a metric all the open balls are supposed to be open.  You can pick any point and any radius, then all the points within that ball form an open set.  I chose $r=\frac k2$ to exclude $b$ so I could conclude that $\{a\}$ must be open.  If I chose $r \gt k$ I would just get that $M$ must be open but I knew that already.  $\{a\}$ is not open because you said that the only open sets were $\emptyset$ and $M$.  The topology is just the set of open sets.

Comment: Ok. Understood now! But (last question), why is it problematic that it is open?

Comment: Why is it problematic that what is open?  You listed the open sets, $\emptyset$ and $M$.  By the definition of a topology, any other set is not open.

Comment: ahhhh. Ok. I completely missed that a topology is the collection of ALL open subsets in M... haha. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Among all the parts of math I have looked at, topology seems to generate more trouble with details of the definitions than any other.  Maybe it is because it is one I self-studied, so I didn't have a teacher to emphasize the importance of the details.

Comment: I'm self studying too :)

Comment: My last question (seriously): why can't I define the constant sequence $X: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{a\},$ defined by $x_n \mapsto a.$ This constant sequence is the only convergent sequence in the set $\{a\}$ and converges to $\{a\}.$ Why is this reasoning, which implies that the subset $\{a\} \subset M$ is closed, incorrect?

Comment: Because that sequence converges to $b$ as well in your topology.  $b$ is in the only open set that contains $a$  You need a $T_1$ space to guarantee that singletons are closed and yours is not.  See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459067/are-singletons-always-closed)  That is why I was harping on the definition of closed sets as complements of open sets.  The limit definition is not equivalent unless the space is $T_1$

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the link and all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Because a metric space is separable. There must open subsets $U,V, a\in U, b\in V, U\cap V$ is empty. Suppose $d$ is a metric, $d(a,b)=r>0$, $B(a,r/2)\cap B(b,r/2)$ is empty.

Comment: I would use the term "Hausdorff" instead of "separable", as "separable" more commonly refers to having a dense countable subset (which not every metric space does).