# Finite set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is not open

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

If we have a finite set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ I am trying to show it is not open using the standard Euclidean metric.

Two strategies come to mind shown as attempt 1 and attempt 2 below:

Attempt 1:
I need to show that not every point is an interior point. Let $A = \{a_{1},a_{2},\dots,a_{n}\}$ be a finite set. Then let $\alpha = \min\{d(x_{i},x_{j}): i \neq j, x_{i}, x_{j} \in A\}$.

Then consider $0<r\leq \alpha$. Then $B(x_{i},r) \cap A = \{x_{i}\}$. But does this intersection also contain the point $\{x_{i}+r\}$? since we are taking the minimum distance between the points (if $r = \alpha$).

If that's the case then $B(x_{i},r) \not \subset A$.

Then I think we can obtain a contradiction, but am a bit stuck.

Attempt 2:

If I can show that in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ a singleton set is not open, then I can construct a finite set as a union on singleton sets and this will then also not be open.

Edited due to comments: Assume A is non-empty but finite.

Comment: ok, strictly speaking one should add that $A$ is not empty. Then, one way of reasoning is contrapositively (think: what's the cardinality of an open ball of positive radius).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Good catch, thanks.

Comment: For singletons see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1459067/399263

Comment: Any (non-empty) open ball must be infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose to the contrary that the non-empty, finite set $A$ is open. Then given $a \in A$ there must be a radius $r>0$ such that $B(a,r) \subseteq A$. But $B(a,r)$ is infinite, and therefore cannot be a subset of a finite set.  Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Your first attempt is close but not quite right. You need to show that *no* ball centered at $x_i$ is contained entirely in $A$. To do this, consider $B(x_i, r)$ for some $r > 0$, and show that you can find some point in $B(x_i, r)$ that isn't in $A$, no matter what $r$ is.

Comment: I'll try it here: Let $r > 0$ and let $\alpha =\min\{d(x_{i},x_{j}):i\neq j x_{i}. x_{j} \in A\}$. Choose $r < \alpha$ Then consider $B(x_{i}, r)$. This contains points in the ball that aren't in A? I don't think this is quite correct though still

Comment: @learningmathematics Your proof should be for **any** $r >0$. By restricting it to $r < \alpha$ your argument is still a bit incomplete. Note a ball $B(x_i,r)$ will contain infinitely many points for any $r>0$ but your set is finite, so...

Comment: @Anurag Thanks, I will try and amend it. I need to practice my logic of negating statements!